# New Active Collab release requires language_id in /accept-invitation API call

Tags: request, activecollab

Since we did updates on Active Collab the API Request returns some Validation Error. (`/accept-invitation`):

```js
{
  "message": "Validation failed",
  "type": "ValidationErrors",
  "field_errors": {
    "language": [
      "Value of language field is required"
    ]
  }
}
```

On Active Collab Side the Users have still the Invation State.

Is there anywhere a Documentation or Changelog where I can check the updates/changes or are there some Settings to do on Active Collab?

https://developers.activecollab.com/api-documentation/v1/people/users/invite.html

On `/accept-invitation`, the `language_id` is optional.

Answer (score 0):

The API has changed a bit recently, and `language_id` is now required when working with user model. You can use 1 as a value. It corresponds to English (en_US.UTF-8).

The team has a new and updated Active Collab docs in works.